# Jenkinsfile: Disable UI parameter based on Git Branch name multibranch pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I am looking for an option for multibranch pipeline where Jenkinsfile should disable/enable a Jenkins UI parameter based on git branch name.

```
parameters {
        string(name: 'Cloud', defaultValue: 'AWS', description: 'Cloud Type')
}
```

But this will show parameter always, I want to show this option only for 'main' branch but not for 'test' branch. How to achieve this? Is this possible to achieve without using 'Active Choices' plugins?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Use the following syntax to set the Parameters, which will give you more flexibility.

```
if ("$BRANCH_NAME".contains("main")) {
    properties([
        parameters([
            string(name: 'Cloud', defaultValue: 'AWS', description: 'Cloud Type')
        ])
    ])
} else {
    println "If not set something different"
}


pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("Hello") {
            steps {
                echo "Building Something"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @ycr, this gives me some good pointer.

Answer (score 1):

On top of @ycr's answer, if you further want to set an environment variable based on the parameter that is defined wrt. the branch, you can use Groovy ternary operator like:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    environment {
        CLOUD_VAR = "${params.Cloud != null ? params.Cloud.toString() : 'AWS'}"
    }
```

I struggled to set such an env. variable in a similar case, therefore, I wanted to share what solved my problem.